# Get data from an API in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am new to asp.net, trying to get data from an api from the moviedb.org and display the data in a react app.
I have my model class ready here

```
namespace MovieApi.Models
{
    public class Movie{
        public double popularity { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool video { get; set; }
        public int vote_count { get; set; }
        public double vote_average { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string original_language { get; set; }
        public string original_title { get; set; }
        public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
        public bool adult { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public string poster_path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following is my attempt to get data from that API but for some reason the

```
httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API Client");
```

Throws an error

*Controllers/ValuesController.cs(20,26): error CS0103: The name 'httpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context [/home/backspace/Downloads/interview-coding-challenge-master/serverside/serverside.csproj]*

```
using System;

using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MovieApi.Models; 

namespace Values.Controllers{
    public class Vals{

        private async Task<Movie> GetMovies()
        {
            // Get an instance of HttpClient from the factpry that we registered
            // in Startup.cs
            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API Client");

            // Call the API & wait for response. 
            // If the API call fails, call it again according to the re-try policy
            // specified in Startup.cs
            var result = await client.GetAsync("/api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1");

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Read all of the response and deserialise it into an instace of
                // Movie class
                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(content);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register it as injectable? Am I missing something or are you not injecting it

Comment: Also, you show your api key which might be a security issue for you now

Comment: I'm not even sure what injection is

Comment: I am Such a noob

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the NuGet package for RestSharp, which gives a simple client for hitting RESTful APIs and deserializing the results into an object.

Information on RestSharp can be found here: http://restsharp.org/

```
 Some pseudo-code:
 _client = new RestClient(BaseUrl); 
 var request = BuildRequest();
 var movie = _client.Execute<Movie>(request);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to take you back a way but are there some recources out there I can use to understand what happening with asp.net core api

Comment: I feel like I'm fumbling my way through this and I'm not really learning

Comment: Any help you can offer me would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am supposed to create a react app that connects to the the asp.net API that gets data from another api

Comment: It's all just messing with my head to be honest

Comment: hey eliot, it's all good buddy, don't stress too much. I've been doing this for 20 and I still feel lost sometimes.

Comment: Totally agree with Shai... we all feel that way sometimes.

Comment: I am happy to help... but I think I am missing something here... why would you want an ASP.net API just to wrap a call to another API?  Is there authentication that needs to added?  Is the other API not publicly accessible?  A little more information might guide me in helping you.

Comment: Here is a quick tutorial on RestSharp.... not perfect for what you want, but it will get you started.  https://www.infoworld.com/article/3489481/how-to-consume-an-aspnet-core-web-api-using-restsharp.html

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you injectable the "httpClientFactory" object in your Startup.cs.
If you injectable, create a constructor in your class to use an instance of his.

```
public class Vals{

    private IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public Vals(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory
    }


    private async Task<Movie> GetMovies()
    {
        // Get an instance of HttpClient from the factpry that we registered
        // in Startup.cs
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API Client");

        // Call the API & wait for response. 
        // If the API call fails, call it again according to the re-try policy
        // specified in Startup.cs
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1");

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read all of the response and deserialise it into an instace of
            // Movie class
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(content);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Visualize this documentation from Microsoft about how to implement HttpClientFactory, I believe it will help you: [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)